# Makefile change libX to X

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

How do I remove the first three bytes in a string to remove the `lib` suffix, for example `libstdc++` to `stdc++`, in GNU `make`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
$(patsubst lib%,%,$(MYLIB))
```

?